# Can't Stablish API Connection through Built App Ionic 4

Tags: android, api, ionic4, angular8

I connected an API on an app that CRUDs info between the app and the Server.

When I test the app on Chrome, it works just perfect, but when I build it and install it on my phone (with Android) no connection works. As I can't check a console on the installed app on my phone, I don't know what's the problem, but I guess the app needs an authorization when it's installed that I don't need when checking the app on a browser.

How can I allow the API connection on the built app?

Note: I have already implemented a connection to get photos from a cloud service, and I get them with no problem, so it's not an internet connection issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect the app to find the Actual error. The issue may be related to CORS. Let me explain the steps to inspect

1.Open the CMD and run

```
a. ionic cordova platform add android
b. ionic cordova build android
```

2.Now open your browser(I prefer **Google Chrome**) and connect your phone with computer. Make sure that the debugging mode is enabled in your phone. Please look it in Google along with your phone version to check how to enable **Debugging in Phone**. Once the phone is connnected , then open Browser , click on **F12 key** and check any error in console. If there is no error, then open network and check is there any response coming from API's.